# How to temporarily disable entity validation on EF 7?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

On EF6 it is possible to temporarily disable entity validation:

```
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
context.SaveChanges();
context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = true;
```

How can we achieve this in EF7?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no validation in EF7 / EF Core.

See this github issue for more info: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/5224